# Idea about creating class structure

Tags: delphi, frameworks

I have a framework that I developed with several classes and components. I would like to create a main object with access to the entire framework so that all developers can access the methods from a single location.

Example:

```
MyApp.Framework.DataBase
MyApp.Framework.DateUtils
MyApp.Framework.Users
MyApp.Framework.System
```

The object `MyApp` maps entire framework and all developers have full access at any time.

The main question is to create a structure that is robust and easy to expand. After a while I would include a structure of functions and methods of the products of our company.

**Example:**

```
MyApp.Blog.    (functions about Blog product)
MyApp.WebDocs. (functions WebDocs product)
```

More example about class:

```
TMyAppBase = Class
Private
  Function GetDatabase: TDataBaseClass;
  Function GetUsers: TSystemUsersClass;
  Function GetForms: TFormManager;
Public
  Constructor Create; Virtual;
  Destructor Destroy; Override;
  Property Database: TDataBaseClass Read GetDatabase;
  Property Users: TSystemUsersClass Read GetUsuarios;
  Property Forms: TFormManager Read GetForms;
End;
```

Using this class:

```
var
  LMyApp: TMyAppBase 

begin
  ShowMessage(LMyApp.Users.ActiveUserName);
end;
```

Would that be friends, I would like if possible ideas from yours. My intention its create a single and expansive structure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I just removed the salutations from your question, as they're considered noise on this site, okay? And, by the way, your English is very good!

Comment: Please try to explain your question again, it's unclear what the question is.

Comment: This sounds like the [Facade design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Don't know if there are any Delphi resources regarding this.

Comment: This is more of a God object than facade actually, cos he plans to expose all the child and childs-child objects. Anyway, it has a right to exist

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object - that's an "antipattern"

Comment: I don't think the question is about a god object, see my answer.

Comment: Create your `MyApp` object - **singleton kernel** (service). and let users to ask this kernel for different services (like `QueryInterface` does). After that you can implement every module (blog, WebDocs) like a separate module and register them in kernel service. in short: you should implement simple extensive plugin system

Comment: I mean, that you should extend you main object (`App.FrameWork`) by adding and registering new Services (`database`, `datautils`) and then querying them,  instead of adding new properties to the `Framework` class. In this case, your main object structure will not change, and it will know nothing about modules types and implementations;

Comment: @UliGerhardt Facade was also my first though, but at second i dont think that will fit. BTW: Design Patterns not limited to Delphi http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade/delphi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've already wrote in my comment, I think in this case it is a good idea to use one main **Service** (main class, singleton) wich can provide you access to other services. All your modules have unique ID (`TGUID`). At the beginning of program execution they should register themselves in main service.
for example. main service unit:

```
unit AppServices;

interface
uses generics.collections, rtti;
type
    // Unique ID Attribute for services
    ServiceIDAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
      strict private
        FId : TGUID;
      public
        constructor Create(ServiceID: string);
        property ID : TGUID read FId;
    end;

    //Services Base class
    TCustomAppService = class(TObject)
      strict protected
      public
    end;

    // Main Service Object
    TAppServices = class(TObject)
      strict private
       class var
        FServices : TObjectDictionary<TGUID, TCustomAppService>;
       var
      public
        class constructor Create();
        class destructor Destroy();
        class procedure RegisterService(aService : TCustomAppService);
        class function QueryService(ServiceID : TGUID):TCustomAppService;
    end;
```

here `class constructor` & `destructor` simply creates and frees  `FServices` Dictionary. `QueryService` method returns Service by its unique ID:

```
class function TAppServices.QueryService(ServiceID: TGUID): TCustomAppService;
begin
    result := nil;
    if FServices.ContainsKey(ServiceID) then
        result := FServices[ServiceID];
end;
```

Method `RegisterService` extracts `RTTI` Attribute (`ServciceIDAttribute`) from parameter's class name and adds this pair (id-service) to dictionary:

```
class procedure TAppServices.RegisterService(aService: TCustomAppService);
var ctx : TRttiContext;
    st : TRttiType;
    a : TCustomAttribute;
    id : TGUID;
begin
    ctx := TRttiContext.Create();
    try
        st := ctx.GetType(aService.ClassType);
        for a in st.GetAttributes() do begin
            if not (a is ServiceIDAttribute) then
                continue;
            id := ServiceIDAttribute(a).ID;

            FServices.AddOrSetValue(id, aService);
            break;
        end;
    finally
        ctx.Free();
    end;
end;
```

now, about end-services. For example UserManager unit:

```
unit UserManager;

interface
uses AppServices;

const
    SID_UserManager : TGUID = '{D94C9E3A-E645-4749-AB15-02631F21EC4E}';
type
    [ServiceID('{D94C9E3A-E645-4749-AB15-02631F21EC4E}')]
    TUserManager = class(TCustomAppService)
      strict private
        FActiveUserName: string;
      public
        property ActiveUserName: string read FActiveUserName;
    end;


implementation


initialization
    TAppServices.RegisterService(TUserManager.Create());
end.
```

now we can test our code:

```
procedure TestApp();
var uMgr :TUserManager;
    dbMgr : TDBmanager;
begin
    dbMgr := TAppServices.QueryService(SID_DBManager) as TDBManager;
    if dbMgr.Connected then
         writeln('connected!')
    else writeln('not connected');

    uMgr := TAppServices.QueryService(SID_UserManager) as TUserManager;
    writeln('Active user: ', uMgr.ActiveUserName);
end;
```

**summary:**
`TAppServices` is the main object, wich provides access to any service in App. It knows nothing about end-services, so it has no dependencies. you can change its implementation as you wish.
You may have as many TCustomAppService class descendants  as you need. When you add new service to application, you shouldn't change `TAppServices` class interface or implementation.

Comment: Hi Teran, this is exactly what I wanted friend.
Easy to expand and that the main object does not need to be modified. Having never worked directly with plugins, I could not envision this idea. Thank you for the tip and sample. It helped a lot.

Thank you all for the ideas and tips.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create a class for this.

Just create a unit named `MyApp.Framework.DataBase` and so on. Delphi supports dots in units which makes it possible to create "namespaces".

Delphi even auto completes when you start typing `Myapp.` in a uses list.

In addition you can create a class `TDataBase` with static methods that you can call with `TDataBase.Method` to organize simple functions/procedures in a common scope.

Comment: Jeans, really, It is a good idea, I had not thought about this question, I will take a look. Thank you.

Comment: Krom and Cosmin, I study a new strategy about my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Delphiman, what *problem* will this solution fix? I've used similar approaches to group static methods in some often used classes, but you're talking about access to classes, and that kind of blurs things. What would be the result of your `MyApp.Blog.CreateNewArticle`? Would it be a `TBlogArticle` class? Or will it be an `ID_ARTICLE:Integer`?

Comment: Hi Cosmin. The solution that the friend Teran showing what I wanted. Exactly that. Something easy to expand.
Only it never worked directly with plugins needed so much and thank your opinions. Helped a lot. Thanks Cosmin.